# Gravity Forms Passing entered data from page 1 to page 2

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am using gravity forms. On page 1, I have Input field for Name and the next button for the next page. I would like to display the data from page 1 into the description on page 2. Anyone can help me? here's the site `https://maverickpreviews.com/programming/Veto/form-page/`

Answer (score 1):

Gravity Forms Populate Anything makes this a breeze with live merge tags.

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/#live-merge-tags

If you're looking to code your own solution, [example #3](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_render/#3-populate-field-with-values-from-earlier-page) on the `gform_pre_render` doc seems to be what you're after.